# AngularJS - Dialog Service Demo has no template Url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been upgrading to Bootstrap 3.03 with Angular for my modals.I am having difficulty setting up a templateUrl.

I checked out the [dialogServiceTest](http://plnkr.co/edit/p17KP6krUlGa7i2JyR4W?p=preview) controller but there is no example for a template URL.

Specifically here is my failed attempt:

```
            case 'logOut':
                var dlg = $dialog.dialog({
                    backdrop: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    backdropClick: true,
                    templateUrl: "logout.html",
                    controller: 'DialogCtl'
                    });
                break;
```

Moreover, I was impressed with the whatsYourNameCtrl and tried to emulate that for my purposes as well (not in plnker):

```
app.run([
        '$q', '$templateCache', '$rootScope',
            function($q, $templateCache, $rootScope) {
                $templateCache.put
                    // logout modal
                    ('/dialogs/logout.html',
                        ' .....
                      <strong class="ng-binding">{{getMemberName}}</strong></span> ?
                          .....                        
                        '<button id="btn1" data-ng-click="yes()" ... >Yes</button>' +
                        '<button id="btn2" data-ng-click="no()" ... >No</button>' +
                          .....
                    );
```

With this $emit call in the CustomDialogCtrl:

```
    $scope.LogOutMemberName = function() {
        $scope.$emit('getMemberName');
    };
```

But it is not hitting the RouteController (Parent of page, ie < body data-ng-controller="RouteCtrl">
which has this call:

```
    $scope.$on('getMemberName', function () {
        console.log('John');
        return 'John';
    });
```

Questions:

1. Might one know of an example to a templateUrl as explained above?
2. Has anyone had any success with a html cache as explained above with an emit call to a parent controller?

Thanks All ...

Answer (score -1):

```
            case 'logout':
                var dlg = $dialogs.create('/app/html/modals/modal-logout.html', 'CustomDialogCtrl', {}, {});
                break;
```

Comment: Please add some comment about what you change to make it work, for future references. Thanks